# How to Group By Column Values?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have these 2 tables

Company

```
CompanyId 
Name
State
Country
```

Tracking

```
Id
CompanyId
Activity
hitDate
```

Now I could have some data like this

Company table

```
1 Company1 AK USA
2 Company2 TX USA
```

Tracking Table

```
1 1 'First Page'  2018-01-01
2 1 'Second Page' 2018-01-01
3 2 'First Page'  2018-01-01
```

Now I want to join these tables together by State and Country

```
 SELECT 
      Count(*) as TotalCount, 
      company.State as State, 
      company.Country as Country, 
      tracking.Activity as Activity
 FROM tracking
 INNER JOIN companies 
    ON tracking.CompanyId=company.CompanyId 
   AND tracking.Activity IN ('First Page', 'Second Page') 
   AND companies.Country = 'USA'  
   AND DATE(tracking.dDateTime) BETWEEN '2018-02-27' AND '2018-02-28'
 GROUP BY  companies.State, companies.Country
 ORDER BY companies.State
```

So I have written a query like above and this gets me results like

```
Total Count - 1
State - AK 
Country - USA
Activity - 'First Page'

Total Count - 1
State - AK 
Country - USA
Activity - 'Second Page'

Total Count - 1
State - Tx
Country - USA
Activity - 'First Page'
```

However I want to get the results to be like this

```
Total Count - 2
State - AK 
Country - USA
Activity - 'First Page, Second Page'

Total Count - 1
State - Tx
Country - USA
Activity - 'First Page'
```

Do I need some sort of subquery to achieve this?

Comment: You typically group by the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Group + order = lost cause

Comment: Your query has errors: `company` is not the same as `companies`. Also the date condition in your query would exclude your sample data.

Comment: please see your query there is a mistake on the second GROUP BY which is tracking.activity instead of companies.Country check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select ...  GROUP_CONCAT(tracking.Activity) as Activity
```

You can also specify the order within the activities and the delimiter:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(tracking.Activity ORDER BY tracking.Activity SEPARATOR ', ')
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not join the counts as I wanted it. It just repeated the Activity name in comma separated value but it was all the same activity

Comment: you should try again, group_concat give you exactly the result you describe

Comment: can you post the whole query up. I run it and all I get is results that has only the first clause in the in statement in it.

Comment: Nobody ever looks for group_concat, but they do sometimes find it in forlorn corners of despair

Comment: @trincot - ok, I tired it again and now I do see it working, I had to add a distinct to the Group_Concat and see that it was actually grouping everything.

Comment: OK, this need was not apparent from your sample data, but good that you could bring it to a solution!